# Transfer data using solidity transfer function

Tags: solidity, blockchain, tokens, ethereum-wallet-dapp, truffle-contract

Can we use transfer function in solidity to transfer the data? 
My code _dest.transfer(txn.value)(txn.data);
and it is showing the error that this type is not callable.

Comment: What do you mean by data? The transfer function from a contract is made to transfer ether from the contract to another address.

Comment: Are you sure we cannot share any comment or data through it....data means any comment or response.

Answer (score 2):

To transfer data from contract A to contract B, you do not use `transfer` function. `transfer` is meant to transfer ether.

But if you want to transfer, lets say an integer, from contract A to contract B, your contract B needs to have a function to receive the int. The contract A needs to know contract B's address.

**Contract A**

```
function transferInteger(int value) {
contractBAddress.saveInteger(value);
}
```

**Contract B**

```
function saveInteger(int value){
//do whatever you want to do with the integer
}
```

EDIT: The code above is very basic. You need to do more stuff to get it working, but I showed this just to give you the concept.